# join variable with variable in which many data contains in row in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want perform join.

```
df1=structure(list(id = 1:3, group_id = c(10L, 20L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

df2 has another structure, in group_id's field contain many groups. For examle `{10,100,400}`
so d`put()`

```
df2=structure(list(id = 1:3, group_id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("{`10`,100,`40`}", 
"{3,`40`,600,100}", "{4}"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

df2 has group_id `10` and `40`,but they are in braces together with other groups.
How get desired joined output

```
id  group_id
1   10
1   40
3   40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean `group_id` in `df2` using `gsub`, bring each id in separate rows and `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(group_id = gsub('[{}`]', '', group_id)) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(group_id) %>%
  filter(group_id %in% df1$group_id)

#  id group_id
#1  1       10
#2  1       40
#3  3       40
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` alternative:

```
df2[, strsplit(gsub('[{}`]', '', group_id), ','), by = id][V1 %in% df1$group_id]
#   id V1
#1:  1 10
#2:  1 40
#3:  3 40
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an option with `base R` using `regmatches/regexpr`

```
subset(setNames(stack(setNames(regmatches(df2$group_id, gregexpr("\\d+", df2$group_id)),
      df2$id))[2:1], c('id', 'group_id')), group_id %in% df1$group_id)
#  id group_id
#1  1       10
#3  1       40
#6  3       40
```